# Cannot find a way to connect electron app with ms-sql-server database file without username and password

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, electron

Want to connect to SQL Server with server name `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` in electron app. How can it be done using a connection string like used in C#? Is there an import which can help me? I also don't have a user name and password in my connection string.

Already used `require('MSSQL')`

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\userdata.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

I want to convert this connection string into a working connection in electron app.

Comment: There's a documentation here https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#configuration-1 the library supports two config formats https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#formats i'm sure you can find everything in there.